# Animate Excel Chart

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-powerpoint, charts, microsoft-excel-2010, animation

I'm preparing for an [Ignite](http://igniteshow.com/) talk and need to figure out how to animate an Excel chart, which will eventually go inside a PowerPoint. I would like to animate the following into a single chart/slide.

Part 1

[image: Chart 1]

Part 2

[image: Chart 2]

Part 3

[image: Chart 3]

As you can see, the y-axis scale changes so animating the y-axis from one step to another is what I need.

Additionally, if it could be made so that the space for all the categories is already defined but remains invisible until triggered, causing the y-axis to scale to fit the new data point, it would be ideal. Example:

[image: E.g. ideal starting point]

I have searched online but haven't found a decent easy to follow tutorial that will allow me to do this. I am using Excel and PowerPoint 2010. Any help anyone can provide will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can think of two possibilities:

1. Create the Parts as individual charts in excel, copy the images into powerpoint, and use powerpoint animation to advance the images
2. If you really want to do it in excel, write VBA macros to modify a single chart as required for each Part, and use `Application.OnTime` to fire the macros at the required interval.

Comment: Hi Chris, thanks for your input. After trying macros for a while, I decided to go with your first suggestion. It isn't quite what I wanted but I think it would be better to spend time on the content of my presentation than the fancy animations inside it.